# Python dict as class variable issue

Tags: python, class, dictionary, variables

I'm running into some problems while using dictionaries are Class variables in Python. I want to have a dict Class variables (a template) that gets added to every instance (users), and subsequently where every instance can change their dict values independently of each other. However, my experience is that changing a dict value in one instance also changes the dict value of the template Class variable and all other instances. This is not the case with variables of type integer, so I'm curious why dicts as class variables exhibit this behavior?

To illustrate, I assembled an example code below where I have two users who (on initialization) gets assigned "their own" dictionary. When adding values to a user, this dictionary is filled by the template dict so that the users can modify the values independently of each other. Or, at least that is what it's supposed to exemplify.

```
class User:
    template = {"sad": 0, "happy": 0, "meloncoli": 0}

    def __init__(self):
        self.emo = {}
    
    def new_dict(self, user_input):
        # add the template to the current instance
        self.emo = self.template
        # if the input values (strings) are in the template, then add 1 instead of 0 as value.
        for i in range(len(list(user_input.values())[0])):
            if list(user_input.values())[0][i] in self.emo:
                self.emo[list(user_input.values())[0][i]] = 1
        

user1 = User()
user_input = {
    6: ["sad", "happy"],
    }
user1.new_dict(user_input)
print(user1.emo)


user2 = User()
user_input = {
    6: ["sad"],
    }
user2.new_dict(user_input)
print(user2.emo)
```

The output I'm getting here is:

```
{'sad': 1, 'happy': 1, 'meloncoli': 0}
{'sad': 1, 'happy': 1, 'meloncoli': 0}
```

However, I should be getting:

```
{'sad': 1, 'happy': 1, 'meloncoli': 0}
{'sad': 1, 'happy': 0, 'meloncoli': 0}
```

This indicates that changing the dict values in the first instance changes them globally. Does anyone have any experience with this? I guess one solution is to add the template dict in the **init** method, but I'm not sure what is best practice in these cases.

Hope someone can enlighten me on this.

Comment: Assignment in Python never copies anything; `self.emo = self.template` just gives a second name to the single existing dict.  `self.emo = self.template.copy()` would be one solution.

Comment: @jasonharper , that solution works fine. Thank you! But my above example works with integer variables. Do you know why this is? Is it a type-specific thing?

Comment: Integers are immutable - anything you might do to change their value necessarily involves assigning a brand-new value to a specific variable name, breaking any connection between that name and other names that shared the original value.  Only a mutable value (such as a dict) can be modified in place; such a change is visible via any other names referring to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue below - no need to use a class variable.

```
class User:

    def __init__(self):
        self.emo = {"sad": 0, "happy": 0, "meloncoli": 0}

    def new_dict(self, user_input):
        # if the input values (strings) are in the template, then add 1 instead of 0 as value.
        for i in range(len(list(user_input.values())[0])):
            if list(user_input.values())[0][i] in self.emo:
                self.emo[list(user_input.values())[0][i]] = 1
```

Running the below:

```
user1 = User()
user_input = {
    6: ["sad", "happy"],
    }
user1.new_dict(user_input)
print(user1.emo)


user2 = User()
user_input = {
    6: ["sad"],
    }
user2.new_dict(user_input)
print(user2.emo)
```

This will yield:

```
{'sad': 1, 'happy': 1, 'meloncoli': 0}
{'sad': 1, 'happy': 0, 'meloncoli': 0}
```